# Setting PHP INI value from command line hangs

Tags: php

I am trying to set an INI setting from the command line (during a codeship build) but the command just hangs every time. I have tried it on a few other machines, and setting different key/values, but the same time every time.

The command I am running is:

```
php -d apc.enable_cli=1
```

I have to ctrl+c to get back to the command line. So far I have tried it on a Mac, Debian, and Mint with the same result every time.

Comment: Does it *hangs* or just waits for input? Is it any different from just `php` without parameters? Do you see a php shell prompt with `php -d apc.enable_cli=1 -a`?

Comment: @AlexBlex ah it seems to wait for input, as it is the same as running just `php`. Does the -d flag only affect that specific instance? If so, how do I write to the ini file if I dont know its location beforehand?

Comment: Yes, command line arguments affects only running process. To get list of loaded configs, run `php -i | grep "\.ini"`.

Comment: Is there no easy way to set a php setting without manually editing the config files? Something similar to `postconf`? Or just setting a config option when installing a php module via `pecl`?

Comment: Sure, one can always use `sed` if `vim` is too complex.